# Create Autowireable @Beans from autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Related:

- [Spring Boot create a list of managed prototype beans from database configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714426/spring-boot-create-a-list-of-managed-prototype-beans-from-database-configuration?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How do I create beans programmatically in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160221/how-do-i-create-beans-programmatically-in-spring-boot)
- [How to programatically add an @Bean definition to Spring context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266608/how-to-programatically-add-an-bean-definition-to-spring-context)

This question is pretty much the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160221/how-do-i-create-beans-programmatically-in-spring-boot), but the answer using `BeanFactoryAware` doesn't solve my problem as the created `@Bean`s are not @Autowireable.

Requirements:

- configure number of beans via spring configuration;
- pick this configuration up via `@ConfigurationProperties`;
- create & inject @Beans based on said config from an autoconfiguration module;
- be able to `@Autowire` created beans in application.

Example:
Make it possible to declare number of caffeine-based `Cache` `@Beans` via spring config. Following is implementation based on the accepted answer from the similar question:

First, the boot autoconfiguration module:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class Props {

    private LocalCacheConf cache = new LocalCacheConf();

    @Data
    public static class LocalCacheConf {

        /**
        * List of caches to create, with accompanying configuration.
        */
        private List<CacheDef> caches = new ArrayList<>();

        @Data
        public static class CacheDef {

            private String name;
            private CaffeineCacheConf properties;
        }

        @Data
        public static class CaffeineCacheConf {

            private long maximumSize = -1;
        }
    }
}


@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LocalCacheConfig implements BeanFactoryAware {

    @Autowired private Props props;
    @Setter private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private CaffeineCacheManager localCacheManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void configure() {
        setCacheManager();
        createCaches( props.getCache() );
    }

    private void createCaches( LocalCacheConf locCacheConf ) {
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

        for ( CacheDef cacheProps : locCacheConf.getCaches() ) {
            Cache cache = createAndConfigureCache(
                    cacheProps.getName(),
                    cacheProps.getProperties()
            );
            configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton( cacheProps.getName(), cache );
        }
    }

    private Cache createAndConfigureCache( String name, CaffeineCacheConf props ) {
        Caffeine<Object, Object> c = Caffeine.newBuilder().recordStats();

        if ( props.getMaximumSize() >= 0 ) {
            c.maximumSize( props.getMaximumSize() );
        }
        // can extend config to include additional properties

        localCacheManager.setCaffeine( c );
        log.info( "building [{}] cache with config: [{}]", name, c.toString() );

        return localCacheManager.getCache( name );
    }

    private void setCacheManager() {
        log.info( "creating {}...", "localCacheManager" );
        localCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        ( (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory )
                .registerSingleton( "localCacheManager", localCacheManager );
    }
}
```

And finally, the using application would define its caches via configuration (yaml here):

```
cache:
  caches:
    - name: c1
      properties:
        maximumSize: 50
    - name: c2
      properties:
        maximumSize: 5000
```

This example is based on the answer from the similar question, but the cache @Beans created this way can't be autowired in the application.

Feels like registering bean definitions in `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` could work, but don't think beanDefs can be used with `Caffeine` instances, as those are created via builder, not property setters.

How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Spring Boot project look at:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine

Comment: Thanks, but the question isn't _really_ about caching; added it just as an example of how the @Autowireable beans should be able to be configured.